# Trying to show Wordpress category query result as background image

Tags: post-thumbnails, query-posts

The code is working fine so far, but I want to show the post thumbnail as a background image inside the li tag. Been trying many variations, but can't work it out? Here's the code:

```
<div class="main-slider" class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
    <?php 
    // Get all posts in 'slider' category
    $post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post_id );
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => array('Interaction','Print','Motion','Image','Sound'),
        'numberposts' => 6,
        'category_name' => 'slider'
    );
    $postQuery = get_posts($args);
    /*query_posts(array('post_type' => 'Interaction',
                        'post_type' => 'Print',
                        'post_type' => 'Motion',
                        'post_type' => 'Image',
                        'post_type' => 'Sound' 
                        )); */              
    foreach( $postQuery as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
            <li class="frontSlider"><?php the_post_thumbnail('feature-slider'); ?>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" title="Go to <?php echo the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                    <div class="flex-captionWrap">
                        <p class="flex-caption"><?php echo get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt; ?></p><!-- Retrieves text string from Captions field in Media -->
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php 
        }
    endforeach; ?>
</ul><!-- .flexslider -->
</div><!-- .flexslider -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to code the output in the manner you want to display it. However you'll have to generate the image link prior to the html part.

1. Save the image in a variable `$bgimage1;`
2. make the list using li and in the list item `backgroun-image: <?php echo $bgimage1; ?>`

Comment: I think you'd need some escaping for that as well really - you're injecting the URL into an HTML attribute value so [`esc_attr()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/).

Comment: if it was sanitized before inputing, then yes, but this is not raw html, it's wordpress generated source of the thumbnail image :)

Comment: Hi Nabeel, thanks for your reply. Could you give an example using the code please.